# C++03: How to get the return type of a function?

Tags: c++, c++03

I have a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    typedef size_t result_type;

    template <class TYPE>
    result_type operator()(const TYPE& type) const;
};
```

I'm testing this struct and I want to be able to assert that the return type of the `operator()` is equal to `size_t`. If I could used C++11, I would go to `decltype`, however, I only have access to C++03. There are a few reasons I want to test something so seemingly obvious:

1. My team have very rigorous testing policies where even things that can be verified visually must be tested
2. Regression testing. I want to make sure this doesn't change in the future.
3. This is a more simplified version of the code, things are a little more complicated and merit a bit more testing in the full version.

What options do I have to do this in C++03? I don't care if it is compile time or run time checking, just something that allows me to do an assert in my test driver.

Comment: In which context do you want to do this check? Obviously the return type is the same.

Comment: Tell us the objective and the context wherein you want to do that. It is not clear what exactly you're trying to do. Are you looking for something like `static_assert` along with `is_same<>`?

Comment: `boost::result_of` could work.

Comment: If it is merely for a test harness, you can simply delegate to a function template the deduces the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++03 does not have a way of directly asking for the return type. You can deduce it with a function template (as Cody Gray suggests in comments) but for your testing purposes you don't need to do that. Just call your function under test and hand the result to an overload set like this:

```
template <typename AnythingElse>
void Foo(AnythingElse const&) { assert(false); }

void Foo(YourType const&) { /* pass */ }
```

That said, I would say testing the return type is probably a mistake -- testing an implementation detail instead of testing results.

Comment: Indeed, +1 for the last sentence. Changing the return type while keeping the expected observable behaviour may be a legitimate refactoring step and probably should not cause a test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enforce binary compatibility of some data structures or messages, you may want to check the properties of the type rather than the type itself.  These may change for what is called size_t in two different architectures.

```
assert(EXPECTED_SIZE == sizeof(result_type));
assert(EXPECTED_MIN == std::numeric_limits<result_type>::min());
assert(EXPECTED_MAX == std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max());
```